# unable to set custom header field for a http destination

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I want to set additional header fields for a given destination. Default call works.

example:

```
Destination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("xyz");
Data data = new DefaultXyzService()
   .withServicePath("/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_XYZ_SRV")
   .getDataByKey(id)
   .execute(destination);
```

But how can i set a custom header field? 
Something like that

```
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
final Header HEADER = new Header("X-XYZ-ENDUSERNAME", id);
headers.add(HEADER);
DefaultHttpDestination destination2 = new DefaultHttpDestination(destination.asHttp(), headers);
Data data = new DefaultXyzService()
   .withServicePath("/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_XYZ_SRV")
   .getDataByKey(id)
   .execute(destination2);
```

results in an error message: **"Unable to fetch the metadata : Error fetching the metadata"**
Using version 3.1.0.

Thanks and best regards,
Volker

Comment: Is the following operation a suitable option for you...?  `.getDataByKey(id).withHeader(String,String).execute(destination.asHttp())`

Comment: That is part of the solution! After reading your comment i saw that the returning object of withHeader has a method onRequestOnly.  `.getDataByKey(id).withHeader(HEADER_ENDUSERNAME,id).onRequestOnly().execute(destination.asHttp());` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API consumers of the *SAP Cloud SDK* are recommended to use the "*withHeader*" method to define individual HTTP request headers for their OData query:

```java
new DefaultXyzService()
   .withServicePath("/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_XYZ_SRV")
   .getDataByKey(id)

   // only on entity request
   .withHeader("foo", "bar").onRequestOnly()

   // on all requests, including $metadata lookup
   .withHeader("fizz", "buzz").onRequestAndImplicitRequests()

   .execute(destiantion.asHttp());
```